# sdl gui based app on remote connection via x11vnc

Tags: freebsd, vnc, x11vnc

am trying to open sdl gui based program in freebsd system from remote connection via x11vnc.

there is no display connected to the pc therefor i used a dummy driver.

keep getting this error

> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/dri-devel/swrast_dri.so" (search paths /usr/local/lib/dri-devel, suffix _dri)
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
> Major opcode of failed request:  150 (GLX)
> Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
> Value in failed request:  0x0
> Serial number of failed request:  234
> Current serial number in output stream:  235

i tired to set SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy but then the program works without seeing any trace of the sdl app GUI

Comment: You might need to make sure that `swrast` is in the `gallium-drivers` meson build option (or the equivalent if another build system, if any, is used). If you got mesa by installing some binary package, you may want to check if it was built with that and whether the particular library has been placed into split package.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had an unneeded package `mesa-devel`.

Uninstalling it solved the problem.